# Can I use the PostgreSQL simple query mode with PHP/PDO?

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, doctrine, pgbouncer

Postgres supports both a [simple and extended](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/protocol.html#PROTOCOL-OVERVIEW) "query mode".

With JDBC I can use `preferQueryMode=simple` to force the driver to use simple mode when issuing queries.

How can I do the same with PDO and the PDO_PGSQL extension in PHP? The server I am currently querying (a PgBouncer instance, to retrieve stats) does *not* support extended mode queries, and all of my queries (issued via Symfony/Doctrine) fail with a `ERROR: unsupported pkt type: 80` error.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` flag to be enabled is enough to prevent extended mode queries from being issued, it seems.

In Symfony you do this by adding an option to the Doctrine YAML config under the relevant connection:

```yaml
  options:
    20: true
```